# No semicolon in encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding

im trying to decode text which is presented in WINDOWS-1251 i believe.
The string looks like this:

```
&#1040&#1075&#1077&#1085&#1090
```

Which should represent **Agent** in Russian. And here is the problem:

1. I'm not able to convert this string unless i add semicolons after each number
2. I cant do it manually, because i have like 10000 lines of text to be converted.

So the question is, what is this encoding (without semicolons) and how can i add them automatically to each line (regex maybe?) without breaking the code.

So far, i've been trying to do this by using this code:

**App Logic**

```
public function parseSentence((array) $sentences, $sentence, $i) {
    if (strstr($sentence, '-')) {
        $sentences[$i] = $this->explodeAndSplit('-', $sentence);
    } else if (strstr($sentence, "'")) {
        $sentences[$i] = $this->explodeAndSplit("'", $sentence);
    } else if (strstr($sentence, "(")) {
        $sentences[$i] = $this->explodeAndSplit("(", $sentence);
    } else if (strstr($sentence, ")")) {
        $sentences[$i] = $this->explodeAndSplit(")", $sentence);
    } else {
        if (strstr($sentence, '#')) {
            $sentences[$i] = chunk_split($sentence, 6, ';');
    }
    return $sentences;
}

/**
 * Explode and Split
 * @param string $explodeBy
 * @param string $string
 *
 * @return string
 */
private function explodeAndSplit($explodeBy, $string) {
    $exp = explode($explodeBy, $string);
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($exp); $j++) {
        $exp[$j] = chunk_split($exp[$j], 6, ';');
    }
    return implode($explodeBy, $exp);
}
```

But obviously, this approach is a bit incorrect (well, totally incorrect), because i'm not taking into account many other 'special' characters. So how can it be fixed?

**Update:**
I'm using Lumen for backend and AngularJS for frontend. Getting all the data parsed in Lumen (database/text files/etc), providing so called API routes for AngularJS to access and retrieve data. And the thing is, this *semicolonless* encoding work great in any browser if accessed directly, but fails to be displayed in Angular due to missing semicolons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [Russian HTML Codes (Cyrillic)](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm). To ensure they are displayed properly, you'll need an appropriate `content-type` applied:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Now to do this correctly, you'll want to [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) the above string of HTML codes you have, accordingly:

```
array_filter(preg_split("/[&#]+/", $str));
```

<sup>*The [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) simply removes any empty values. You could ultamitely use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) too, to do the same thing.*</sup>

---

This will return an array of the numbers you have. From there, a simple `implode()` with the required prepended `&#` and appended `;` is simple:

```
echo '&#' .implode( ";&#", array_filter(preg_split("/[&#]+/", $str) )) . ';';
```

Which returns:

```
&#1040;&#1075;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;
```

Now when generated as correct HTML, it displays the following Russian text:

```
Агент
```

Which translates directly to `Agent` in Russian.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this amazing walk-through with my problem, simple solution, really appreciate

Comment: @IvanZhivolupov My pleasure! I'm glad it helped you to resolve your issue!